# Replacing multiple words in a string from different data sets in Python

Tags: python, string, random

Essentially I have a python script that loads in a number of files, each file contains a list and these are used to generate strings. For example: "Just been to see $film% in $location%, I'd highly recommend it!" I need to replace the $film% and $location% placeholders with a random element of the array of their respective imported lists.

I'm very new to Python but have picked up most of it quite easily but obviously in Python strings are immutable and so handling this sort of task is different compared to other languages I've used.

Here is the code as it stands, I've tried adding in a while loop but it would still only replace the first instance of a replaceable word and leave the rest.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random

def replaceWord(string):
   #Find Variable Type
   if "url" in string:
       varType = "url"
   elif "film" in string:
       varType = "film"
   elif "food" in string:
       varType = "food"
   elif "location" in string:
       varType = "location"
    elif "tvshow" in string:
        varType = "tvshow"

   #LoadVariableFile
   fileToOpen = "/prototype/default_" + varType + "s.txt"
   var_file = open(fileToOpen, "r")
   var_array = var_file.read().split('\n')

   #Get number of possible variables
   numberOfVariables = len(var_array)

   #ChooseRandomElement
   randomElement = random.randrange(0,numberOfVariables)

   #ReplaceWord
   oldValue = "$" + varType + "%"
   newString = string.replace(oldValue, var_array[randomElement], 1)

   return newString

testString = "Just been to see $film% in $location%, I'd highly recommend it!"
Test = replaceWord(testString)
```

This would give the following output: Just been to see Harry Potter in $location%, I'd highly recommend it!

I have tried using while loops, counting the number of words to replace in the string etc. however it still only changes the first word. It also needs to be able to replace multiple instances of the same "variable" type in the same string, so if there are two occurrences of $film% in a string it should replace both with a random element from the loaded file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program may be somewhat closer to what you are trying to accomplish. Please note that documentation has been included to help explain what is going on. The templates are a little different than yours but provide customization options.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import random


PATH_TEMPLATE = './prototype/default_{}s.txt'


def main():
    """Demonstrate the StringReplacer class with a test sting."""
    replacer = StringReplacer(PATH_TEMPLATE)
    text = "Just been to see {film} in {location}, I'd highly recommend it!"
    result = replacer.process(text)
    print(result)


class StringReplacer:

    """StringReplacer(path_template) -> StringReplacer instance"""

    def __init__(self, path_template):
        """Initialize the instance attribute of the class."""
        self.path_template = path_template
        self.cache = {}

    def process(self, text):
        """Automatically discover text keys and replace them at random."""
        keys = self.load_keys(text)
        result = self.replace_keys(text, keys)
        return result

    def load_keys(self, text):
        """Discover what replacements can be made in a string."""
        keys = {}
        while True:
            try:
                text.format(**keys)
            except KeyError as error:
                key = error.args[0]
                self.load_to_cache(key)
                keys[key] = ''
            else:
                return keys

    def load_to_cache(self, key):
        """Warm up the cache as needed in preparation for replacements."""
        if key not in self.cache:
            with open(self.path_template.format(key)) as file:
                unique = set(filter(None, map(str.strip, file)))
            self.cache[key] = tuple(unique)

    def replace_keys(self, text, keys):
        """Build a dictionary of random replacements and run formatting."""
        for key in keys:
            keys[key] = random.choice(self.cache[key])
        new_string = text.format(**keys)
        return new_string


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This actually worked brilliantly for what I needed, thank you!

Comment: If you found it to be useful, you might consider voting on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few points about your code:

- You can replace the randrange with [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) as you just
  want to select an item from an array.
- You can iterate over your types and do the replacement without
  specifying a limit (the third parameter), then assign it to the same object, so you keep all your replacements.
- readlines() do what you want for open, read from the file as store the lines as an array
- Return the new string after go through all the possible replacements

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random

def replaceWord(string):
   #Find Variable Type
   types = ("url", "film", "food", "location", "tvshow")
   for t in types:
      if "$" + t + "%" in string:
        var_array = []
        #LoadVariableFile
        fileToOpen = "/prototype/default_" + varType + "s.txt"
        with open(fname) as f:
           var_array = f.readlines()

        tag = "$" + t + "%"
        while tag in string:
            choice = random.choice(var_array)
            string = string.replace(tag, choice, 1)
            var_array.remove(choice)

   return string

testString = "Just been to see $film% in $location%, I'd highly recommend it!"
new = replaceWord(testString)
print(new)
```

Comment: That works wonderfully, only downside to it is the string returned appears to be now on multiple lines however removing the line breaks was easy enough!

Comment: Nice to hear, please upvote/accept the answer as it solved your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Just noticed an issue with it, when including multiple instances of the same type, so for example two films it will assign the same random choice to both rather than unique random values

Comment: @SamB Just changed it to handle this case, you just need to replace one by one, taking care to not repeat an item.

Comment: Just noticed an odd issue, if for example there is three different types, but two of them are the same, neither of the same ones will be replaced. i.e. "Going to $location% with $name% and %name$" will only replace the location part, it works if working with just strings but working with lines from a file seems to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Seems sometimes items are just not being picked up too regardless of the number of times they appear in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The `varType` you are assigning will be set in only one of your `if-elif-else` sequence and then the interpreter will go outside. You would have to run all over it and perform operations. One way would be to set flags which part of sentence you want to change. It would go that way:

```
url_to_change = False
film_to_change = False
if "url" in string:
    url_to_change = True
elif "film" in string:
    film_to_change = True

if url_to_change:
    change_url()
if film_to_change:
    change_film()
```

If you want to change all occurances you could use a `foreach` loop. Just do something like this in the part you are swapping a word:

```
for word in sentence:
    if word == 'url':
        change_word()
```

Having said this, I'd reccomend introducing two improvements. Push changing into separate functions. It would be easier to manage your code.
For example function for getting items from file to random from could be

```
def load_variable_file(file_name)
    fileToOpen = "/prototype/default_" + file_name + "s.txt"
    var_file = open(fileToOpen, "r")
    var_array = var_file.read().split('\n')
    var_file.clos()
    return var_array
```

Instead of

```
if "url" in string:
    varType = "url"
```

you could do:

```
def change_url(sentence):
    var_array = load_variable_file(url)
    numberOfVariables = len(var_array)
    randomElement = random.randrange(0,numberOfVariables)
    oldValue = "$" + varType + "%"
    return sentence.replace(oldValue, var_array[randomElement], 1)

if "url" in sentence:
    setnence = change_url(sentence)
```

And so on. You could push some part of what I've put into change_url() into a separate function, since it would be used by all such functions (just like loading data from file). I deliberately do not change everything, I hope you get my point. As you see with functions with clear names you can write less code, split it into logical, reusable parts, no needs to comment the code.